# Docker fixed date

Tags: linux, node.js, mongodb, date, docker

I have a docker container running a mongo server, and a docker node application that connects to it.
In mongo I have data that is dumped daily, and node has logic to use yesterdays date when doing queries.

This is a test setup that I want to use without updating the mongo database daily.

Is there a way to specify a fixed date to docker or node so that the data in mongo is still relevant?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to specify a fixed date to docker or node

No, not without impacting the host (running the docker daemon) as well.

Maybe you can try running commands with [`faketime`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/faketime.1.html) installed.

Comment: Thx for the help! It's kind of working. I mean on my machine it's ok, but on the build server i get the following error: "Invalid clock_id for clock_gettime: 6mongo" and I can't find any fix online :(